# Access ScrollView properties of a DataGrid in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

Is it possible to access the horizontal offset, which I can't find in the property list of the datagrid ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In XAML

```
 <DataGrid Name="dataGrid1" ..... />
```

If you want to access to the HorizontalOffset you need to access to the ScrollViewer contained inside the Datagrid

one possible method to access the ScrollViewer is

```
for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dataGrid1); i++)
{
       if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dataGrid1, i) is ScrollViewer)
    {
              ScrollViewer scroll =
        (ScrollViewer)(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dataGrid1, i));
                           Console.WriteLine(scroll.HorizontalOffset);
    }
}
```

Note that `scroll.HorizontalOffset` is read-only

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I will try it. I know that the property is read-only, but there is a function caled ScrollToHorizontalOffset which let me modify it.

Comment: It's not exactly that, but close enough. Datagrid do have a visual child, but it's a border, which in turn has the ScrollViewer, so a double loop was used and it now works.

Comment: @Klaus78 Mate could you take a look on my question its almost same like this, I tried your code but its not working for me :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39790008/how-to-save-position-after-reload-datagrid-in-wpf

Answer (score 0):

Just name the base control (e.g. ListView) in XAML and access it by name in the code behind.