# How to save position after reload DataGrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, window

I'm talking about DataGrid **not DataGridView**!
What I'm doing here is refreshing datagrid which contains `<DataGrid.GroupStyle>` and I'm showing my data from database grouped by number of order, and what I want to do is refresh my datagrid.

Here is my code:

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        try
        {


            InitializeComponent();


            this.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
            this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;

            var ordersList = OrdersController.localOrders();


            collectionViewSource.Source = ordersList;
            collectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("NumberOfOrder"));
            DataContext = collectionViewSource;

            DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(8);
            timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
            timer.Start();

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var ordersList = OrdersController.localOrders();
        collectionViewSource.Source = null;
        collectionViewSource.Source = ordersList;

        DataContext = collectionViewSource;

        datagrid1.ScrollIntoView(datagrid1.Items[datagrid1.Items.Count - 1]);
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"  BorderBrush="#83D744" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" VerticalGridLinesBrush="Transparent" Grid.Column="0"   RowHeaderWidth="0" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  x:Name="datagrid1" Margin="10,150,8,50" Background="Transparent" RowBackground="#FF494949"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#83D744"/>
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
            </Style>


    <Style x:Key="TextInCellCenter" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" >
        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="RightAligElementStyle">
        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Right"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="LeftAligElementStyle">
        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    </Style>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" 
               Color="Transparent"/>
    </DataGrid.Resources>


    <DataGrid.Columns >
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ProductName}"     ElementStyle="{StaticResource LeftAligElementStyle}"     Header="NAZIV ARTIKLA" MinWidth="350"    Foreground="White" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Verdana" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Quantity}"        ElementStyle="{StaticResource TextInCellCenter}"         Header="KOLIČINA"   MinWidth="200" Foreground="White"      FontSize="20" FontFamily="Verdana" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>

    <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <!-- Style for groups at top level. -->
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                <Expander IsExpanded="True"  Background="Black" Opacity="0.7">
                                    <Expander.Header >
                                        <DockPanel Height="50" Margin="0,0,0,0"  Name="dockPanel" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=ActualWidth}">

                                            <Button Name="btnFinishOrder" Content="Finish Order" Margin="0,0,55,5" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Click="btnFinishOrder_Click" FontSize="12" BorderThickness="1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"  Foreground="#83D744"  Background="Transparent"  BorderBrush="#83D744" Width="130"   Height="40">
                                                 <Button.Template>
                                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                                    <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                                            BorderBrush=    "{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                                            Background=     "{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                                                    </Border>
                                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                                 </Button.Template>
                                             </Button>

                                             <Button Name="btnTakeIt" Click="btnTakeIt_Click"  Content="Take it" Margin="0,0,20,5" DockPanel.Dock="Right" FontSize="12" BorderThickness="1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"  Foreground="#83D744"  Background="Transparent"  BorderBrush="#83D744" Width="130"   Height="40">
                                                 <Button.Template>
                                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                                    <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                                                    </Border>
                                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                                 </Button.Template>
                                            </Button>
                                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Normal" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="20" Height="25" Foreground="#83D744" Text="{Binding Path=Name,StringFormat= Number of Order:# {0}}" />

                                        </DockPanel>
                                    </Expander.Header>
                                    <Expander.Content>
                                        <ItemsPresenter />
                                    </Expander.Content>
                                </Expander>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        </GroupStyle>
    </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

after reload data, cell selection jumps on first column and scrollbars is reset. How to save position of DataGrid?

Comment: I've made an edit to my answer, please check if the new solution works for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to scroll to specific item, just save the index and use:

```
dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(dataGrid.Items[itemIndex]);
```

You can use this to scroll to the last item in the DataGrid:

```
dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(dataGrid.Items[dataGrid.Items.Count - 1]);
```

**EDIT:**

There seems to be a problem with `DataGrid` scrolling when using `CollectionViewSource` and grouping.

I managed to get it to work the other way... Instead of

```
dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(dataGrid.Items[dataGrid.Items.Count - 1])
```

try using the following code to do the scrolling:

```
if (datagrid1.Items.Count > 0)
{
    var border = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(datagrid1, 0) as Decorator;
    if (border != null)
    {
        var scrollViewer = border.Child as ScrollViewer;
        if (scrollViewer != null) scrollViewer.ScrollToEnd();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where should I place it exactly on my code, I just executed and I probably placed it on wrong place..

Comment: It should work if you place it at the end of your `timer_Tick` method.

Comment: BandaI placed it there and acctually after my screen refresh nothing is happening , still same like before

Comment: It works for regular DataGrid, can't be sure what is the problem without seeing all of your code... Try adding `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"` to your XAML DataGrid definition. If it doesn't work, edit your question and add all code, including XAML.